# Importing external CSS file when converting to HTML

Tags: java, docx4j

I'm trying to convert a *docx* file to an *HTML* file using the given sample program.
The sample suggests:

```
String userCSS = "html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, img, 
  ol, ul, li, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td " +
                      "{ margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}" +
                   "body {line-height: 1;} ";
htmlSettings.setUserCSS(userCSS);
```

Even though `setUserCSS` is a depreciated method.
This works fine, but I have my own css file that I would like to use.
I would like to avoid extracting it as a string from the file where possible.

As well as this, I would like to combine multiple css files such that the top of the resultant output html contains:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet1.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css"/>
```

in the head.

That, or finding an alternative to the `setUserCSS` method that I can call on the HTMLSettings class.

Couldn't find much for this case, only for the other way around. Any solution is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language are you using to write such kind of program. But you can do that by just writing a function that would convert the path of a file into css link.

For example:

```
htmlSettings.loadCSS('path/stylesheet1.css');
```

this will converted to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/stylesheet1.css"/>
```

Comment: I'm using the docx4j library as found here: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j.

They do not have a loadCSS method, and I don't have the ability to override that.

I could in theory yes write a function which reads the contents of that css file and converts it to a string, but as said, I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The focus of docx4j's HTML output is on creating CSS based on the formatting in the document.

That said, if the HTML is being created via XSLT, the relevant code is in the createStyleElement method in [XsltHTMLFunctions.java](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/html/XsltHTMLFunctions.java)

If you are using the non-XSLT approach, it is in HTMLExporterVisitorDelegate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I think I may be misunderstanding or have misworded, but I'm not using ImportXHTML - I have a doc file and I want to generate HTML; I want to provide a stylesheet to the HTML output.

If what you have replied does that, then my apologies for not understanding how to implement, but I think I am trying to do something different.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but I'm still not entirely sure how HTMLExporterVisitorDelegate handles an external css file. I'm using the FLAG_EXPORT_PREFER_XSL as the third argument for the toHTML method I'm calling, and would ideally like to pass these files in as some argument to a method on the HTMLSettings object I pass in as the first argument. Does this seem possible?

Comment: Another way of wording for clarity would be; is there a method I can use instead of `HTMLSettings.setUserCSS()` that would let me just pass in a single instance of something that allows `Docx4J.toHTML` to behave as intended?

Thanks.